# Get musicians/band verified facebook pages

Tags: facebook

How do I query Facebook to select only verified band/musicians pages?

I used Tool explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2 and query this `me/music/?fields=category,name,id,band_members` but as result I just got all kind of pages not including the official ones.

Is that possible or does Facebook not offer any specific parameter to get this info?

Comment: I think you might mean "Verified" rather than "authenticate"? - https://www.facebook.com/help/196050490547892

Comment: Thank you Sam, exactly I meant Verified.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to filter this via the Graph API endpoints. If you can use FQL (meaning you app is a <=v2.0 app), you could use the following query:

```
select page_id, name from page where is_verified = 'true' and page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid=me())
```